# struts2, How to update Standard two-column table layout for the HTML Struts Tags without changing theme

Tags: jsp, struts2

I'm using struts2 for my application. In struts2,by default lays forms out in a two column table with the label for each input field in the left column and the input field in the right column (Label #input field#). But in my case, I need four-column in a row (Label #input field#  Label #input field#). is there any way to do this, without changing my theme(xhtml) ?

I don't want any changes to theme, is there any way to cheat auto rendering #tr#,#td# tags for each struts tag.

Comment: Use `simple` theme and layout elements like you want.

Comment: For my application, i'm using struts2 validation.but if I use simple theme, I can't use struts2 validation framework.

Comment: You can use Struts2 validation despite of theme used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need four columns in a row then you need to fully control the `<s>` tag or just skip `<s>` tags and have your own form :)

To align all controls yourself, I would suggest you to use css_xhtml theme instead of default xhtml.

By doing so suppose your form is like this:

```
<s:form action="add" method="post">
    <s:textfield name="contact.firstName" label="Firstname"/>
    <s:textfield name="contact.lastName" label="Lastname"/>
</s:form>
```

It will be rendered as:

```
<form id="add" name="add" action="add" method="post">
    <div id="wwgrp_add_contact_firstName" class="wwgrp">
        <div id="wwlbl_add_contact_firstName" class="wwlbl">
        <label for="add_contact_firstName" class="label">Firstname:</label>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="wwctrl_add_contact_firstName" class="wwctrl">
        <input type="text" name="contact.firstName" value="" id="add_contact_firstName"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wwgrp_add_contact_lastName" class="wwgrp">
        <div id="wwlbl_add_contact_lastName" class="wwlbl">
        <label for="add_contact_lastName" class="label">Lastname:</label>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="wwctrl_add_contact_lastName" class="wwctrl">
        <input type="text" name="contact.lastName" value="" id="add_contact_lastName"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

All you have to do now is override the style and create your forms accordingly ,style them :)